# AngularJS list items alphanumerically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I've been working on sorting a list of items alphanumerically. I have found that using ng-repeat with orderBy tends to sort either numerically or alphabetically depending on the type of data it is working with. It does not however sort alphanumerically.

JavaScript Code:

```
    function AppCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
             {'name':'School Item 1','address':'1920'},
             {'name':'Work Item 2','address':'4192'},
             {'name':'Ad Item 5','address':'2039'},
             {'name':'Cool Item 45','address':'2090'},
             {'name':'Cool Item 50','address':'1029'},
             {'name':'Cool Item 100','address':'1829'},
             {'name':'Cool Item 400','address':'1728'}
        ];
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
    <ul ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items|orderBy:['name','address']">
             {{item.name}} {{item.address}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roverton/PuYLS/1/

Notice that when ordered the it will show 1 then 100, 45 then 400, 5 then 50 etc. I would like to order these alphanumerically. How would I do that in AngularJS?

Comment: Create a custom filter. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/angularjs-custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat/12041694#12041694) may also help.

Comment: If the name is static, you could just add another field to the model for the purposes of sorting and only have the integer value in that field.

Comment: Unfortunately the name is not static. It varies from one item to another. I've updated my example to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a function to extract the number.

```
function nameNumberSorter(item) {
    var numberPart = item.name.replace('NamedItem', '');
    return parseInt(numberPart);
}
```

And then alter your filter a bit:

```
<div ng-app>
    <ul ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items|filter:deviceBindingFilter|orderBy:nameNumberSorter">
            {{item.name}} - {{item.address}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Alternatively**, you could make an extra field on your model for sorting.

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
         {'name':'NamedItem1','address':'1920', 'sortOrder': 1 },
         {'name':'NamedItem2','address':'4192', 'sortOrder': 2 },
         {'name':'NamedItem5','address':'2039', 'sortOrder': 5 },
         {'name':'NamedItem45','address':'2090', 'sortOrder': 45 },
         {'name':'NamedItem50','address':'1029', 'sortOrder': 50 },
         {'name':'NamedItem100','address':'1829', 'sortOrder': 100 },
         {'name':'NamedItem400','address':'1728', 'sortOrder': 400 }
    ];
}
```

And change your sort to look at this field.

```
<div ng-app>
    <ul ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items|filter:deviceBindingFilter|orderBy:'sortOrder'">
            {{item.name}} - {{item.address}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the solution which you've suggested. Though removing the alphabetical characters would not work. Your solution sorts the items numerically. Is there a way to sort the items alphanumerically? 

I've updated my question to show what I am talking about. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, if you know how many digits there will be at a maximum, you can still solve this by replacing all instances of a number by the same number with leading zeros up to the maximum number.  I.E. `NamedItem1` would become `NamedItem0001`, and `NamedItem45` would become `NamedItem0045` and `NamedItem400` would become `NamedItem0400`.  This replacement is almost as easy as what I have shown above.

Comment: Nick, That will totally work I know exactly how many items will exist in the list. Thank you! :)