# orderBy does nothing when fed by a function result

Tags: angularjs

I use `ng-repeat` to display a list of tasks:

```
<div class="task_container" ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:weigth(task)">
    <span >Task:<span><br><span>{{task.label}}</span>
</div>
```

Each task has some properties, and I have defined a weight function that sums up these properties:

```
function weight(task)
{
    var weight_value = task.priority - task.difficulty + task.interest;
    return weight_value;
}
```

However, when displaying the page, the tasks are not ordered at all.

Is there a better/correct way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do that :

```
<div class="task_container" ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:weigth">
    <span >Task:<span><br><span>{{task.label}}</span>
</div>
```

A jsFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/zjvsu/1/

Another complete post here : [Custom sort function in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/angularjs-custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat/12041694#12041694)

And attach your weight function to the $scope

Comment: Another mistake I did is that I had not defined my weight function inside $scope.

Comment: Oh i thought was juste for thé exemple i update thé answer ans you van accept