# Angular js - sorting in table based on letter ASCII value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I've done a basic table sorting application using angular, sorting is doing but the problem is that i'm not getting the values sorted in ASCII value

can anyone please tell me how to do it

[**[DEMO]**](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/19/)

**html**

```
    <div ng-app ng-controller="ArrayController">
        <table>
            <th ng-repeat="header in headers">
                <a ng-click="sort_by(header)">{{ headers[$index] }}</a>
            </th>
            <tr ng-repeat="arr in records |orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
                <td ng-repeat="val in arr" ng-bind-html-unsafe="arr[headers[$index]]"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**script**

```
    function ArrayController($scope) {
    $scope.headers = ['col1', 'col2'];
    $scope.records = [{col1: 'a1', col2: 'd1'}, {col1: 'c2', col2: 'A2'}, {col1: 'b3', col2: 'c3'}, {col1: 'd4', col2: 'a1'}];

    $scope.reverse = true;
     $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder)
        {
            if ($scope.sortingOrder === newSortingOrder)
            {
              $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
            }
            $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

          };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom orderBy function, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/angularjs-custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat) for more details.

Comment: here you go, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/19/), the main point is charCodeAt.

Comment: yes...this is my custom sort method
`$scope.myValueFunction = function(values) { 
$scope.cards.sort(function(str1, str2) 
{ 
console.log(str1.name); 
console.log(str2.name); 
return ( ( ('aaa').compareTo('sds') ) ? 0 : ( ( str1 > str2 ) ? 1 : -1 ) ); 
}); 
}`...........but i'm getting TypeError: Object aaa has no method 'compareTo'

Comment: Seems in javascript, string doesn't have compareTo method.

Comment: sorry, I just realised I didn't save the jsfiddle, actually I already did, let me try to rewrite.