# AngularJs ng-repeat orderBy not working for nested object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I,m trying to ng-repeat nested object properties and order them, but the ordering isn't working for me.

I've seen this:
[How to orderby in AngularJS using Nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723417/how-to-orderby-in-angularjs-using-nested-property)

but the json structure is different and i couldn't get it to work.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8QMt66mJgr8KQ97wwI7?p=preview)

My code:

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:order.allListPosition">
       <div>{{item.name}} - {{item.order}}</div>
   </div>
```

The scope:

```
   $scope.data = {
           "78962": {
                 "id": "78962",
                 "name": "item 2",
                 "type": "blind",
                 "order": {
                       "allListPosition": "008",
                       "catListPosition": "059"
                       },
                 "data": {
                       "status": "stop",
                       "percent": 20
                       },
                 "longPress": {
                       "item": "78966",
                       "active": true
                      }
           },
            "78963": {
                   "id": "78963",
                   "name": "item 3",
                   "type": "coolmaster",
                   "order": {
                         "allListPosition": "053",
                         "catListPosition": "001"
                    },
                    "data": {
                           "status": 1,
                           "temp": 16,
                           "point": 25,
                           "mode": "cool",
                           "fan": 3
                          },
                 "longPress": {
                           "item": "78966",
                           "active": false
                            }
               }
            };
```

Can anyone please show me what am i doing wrong?

Thank's alot

Avi

Comment: Use orderBy:'order.allListPosition'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two reasons `orderBy` isn't working here:

- `orderBy` only works on arrays, but you are applying it to a plain object.
- To order by an expression, you need to give `orderBy` a string value with the expression. You are giving it `order.allListPosition`, which would equate to `$scope.order.allListPosition` (which doesn't exist).

To solve the first issue, add an array of your data objects:

```
$scope.dataArray = Object.keys($scope.data)
  .map(function(key) {
    return $scope.data[key];
  });
```

To solve the second issue (and incorporate the `dataArray` from above):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in dataArray | orderBy:'order.allListPosition'">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/BXgYPTElSM3sjvLg30CL?p=preview

Comment: **THANK YOU**. I owe you a damn nice lunch and drinks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom filter to order by neasted properties.

```
myApp.filter('customorder', function() {
   return function(items) {  
    items.sort(function(a,b){
        // Make sure we are comparing integers
        var aPos = parseInt(a.order.allListPosition);
        var bPos = parseInt(b.order.allListPosition);

        // Do our custom test
        if (aPos  > bPos ) return 1;
        if (aPos < bPos) return -1;         
        return 0; 
    })
   }
 });
```

Your html will look like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | customorder">
   <div>{{item.name}} - {{item.order}}</div>
</div>
```

You should always think that angular is not a restritive language. the filters you normally use are [built in filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter). But you can have fun with your own filter as soon as you need!

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your answer.

because the  $scope.data is an object you can't use sort.

can you please show me a plunker example?

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` object is an object of objects, and not an array of objects.

Therefore, `orderBy` won't work since it is only compatible with arrays.

I have updated your `data` object to make it work:

```
$scope.data = [
             {              
              "id": "78961",
              "name": "item 1",
              "type": "blind",
              "order":{allListPosition:"093",catListPosition: "009"}, 
              "data": {
                  "status": "up",
                  "percent": 80
              },
              "longPress": {
                  "item": "78966",
                  "active": true
              }

            },
            {  
              "id": "78962", 
              "name": "item 2",
              "type": "blind",
                "order":{allListPosition:"008",catListPosition: "059"},
              "data": {
                  "status": "stop",
                  "percent": 20
              },
              "longPress": {
                  "item": "78966",
                  "active": true
              }
            },
            {

              "id": "78963",
              "name": "item 3",
              "type": "coolmaster",
                "order":{allListPosition:"053",catListPosition: "001"},
              "data": {
                  "status": 1,
                  "temp": 16,
                  "point": 25,
                  "mode": "cool",
                  "fan": 3
              },
              "longPress": {
                  "item": "78966",
                  "active": false
              }

            }];
```

And in HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'order.allListPosition'">
   <div>{{item.name}} - {{item.order}}</div>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWYMZrGKeEZBsrBJaRNg?p=preview)

Comment: Thank's alot
but i can't change the data object.
that is how i get the data from the api.

is there a workaround?

Answer (score -3):

I'm pretty sure this should be:

`<div ng-repeat="item in dataArray | orderBy:'item.order.allListPosition'">`