# angularjs orderBy filter not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using orderBy filter for date field in angularjs and this is not working.

### main.js

```
    var data = [{name:'A',event_details:{event_start_date:'2015-12-31T00:00:00.000Z'}},{name:'B',event_details:{event_start_date:'2016-12-31T00:00:00.000Z'}}]
```

### index.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed responsive mb0" datatable="ng" >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Start Date</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:'event_details.event_start_date'">
                                    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{x.event_details.event_start_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

result is sorting on the basis on first colimn i.e name although i have specified to order by start date.

Can anybody help me over this issue.

Comment: Are you using the orderBy, or the date filter? Those are two different filters. And how? Where is your code? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate. See this answer for a good explanation. There are 2 perfectly good answers for this question among this question.

[How to orderby in AngularJS using Nested property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723417/how-to-orderby-in-angularjs-using-nested-property)

### index.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:'event.createdAt'">
    <td>{{x.event.createdAt}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still objects are not in order. they are in random order.

Comment: Are you certain they are not being sorted alphabetically?