# Use the Angular 'orderBy' filter with array & function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

The array of objects that I want to sort looks like this:

```
var students = [
                {'name': 'AAA',
                'year': 'freshman',
                'score': 90,},

                {'name': 'ABA',
                'year': 'sophomore',
                'score': 100},
                ...
                ];
```

Custom sorting function:

```
function customOrder(value) {
    switch(value){
        case 'freshman':
            return 0;
        case 'sophomore':
            return 1;
        case 'junior':
            return 2;
        case 'senior':
            return 3;
    }
}
```

And I'm using the Angular orderBy filter:

```
students = $filter('orderBy')(students, function(item) {
    return customOrder(item.year);
};
```

With the above code, I can sort the students array by year.  But I want to sort the array like this: **year: DESC**, then **name: ASC**, then **score: DESC**.

I made an array for this:

```
$scope.sortArray = ['name', '-score'];
```

And I changed the sorting logic like this:

```
students = $filter('orderBy')(students, [function(item) {
    return customOrder(item.year);
}, $scope.sortArray]); // I don't want to hard code here (i.e. 'name', '-score')
```

But it gives an error.

Is there any possible way to sort the students array?

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/angularjs-custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat