# How does one use a reserved character in an Angular predicate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using some data from Google Analytics in my app, which uses colons in the hash keys. For example,

```
var pages = [{
    'ga:sessions': 100,
    'ga:adImpressions': 1000
}, ...];
```

But Angular runs into problems when I want to order by something with a colon. This:

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages | orderBy:'ga:sessions':true">
```

Throws this:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected
token at column 3 of the expression [ga:sessions] starting at
[:sessions].
```

EDIT: Here's what I've already tried:

1. Storing the key in a var and using orderBy:myKey:true
2. Escaping the colon with \
3. And in an act of desperation, using the unicode escape code for colon

Comment: I believe you can flip the quote markers: `'page in pages | orderBy:"ga:sessions":true'`

Comment: try to escape it - \:

Comment: No luck with either unfortunately. I'll add what I've already tried to the question.

Comment: If for some reason that doesn't work, you can assign it to a scope variable: `$scope.gaSessions="ga:sessions"; ... "page in pages | orderBy:gaSessions:true"`

Comment: Actually that doesn't work either haha. See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function which will return a value at the specific key of each object in array:

```
$scope.filterFunc = function (obj){
    return obj['ga:sessions'];
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages | orderBy:filterFunc:true">
```

See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041694/2046306).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it this way because angular parser will not allow you.

You can write your own filter or fix keys before converting them to object.

UPD: Technically it's not valid attribute name according to ECMAScript 5.1 https://es5.github.io/#x7.6

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure escaping the character should work, I found a jsfiddle where they use the escape character() in front of the colon as an example

http://jsfiddle.net/CBgcP/664/

```
 <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | weDontLike:'Adam\:Adamson'">
```

Edit: I see that you have tried this already but it seems to work in the jsfiddle. I'll see if I cant find another solution.

Comment: In this example it's an attribute value, not attribute name :(