# AngularJS - ng-repeat print me (user_id) first, then order by

Tags: angularjs

I need to loop trough object of users but I want to place a concrete user (me) at the beginning.

Example

```
this.users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Jane"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "John"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Me"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Mark"
    }
];

<div ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users">
    <!-- SOME OTHER TAGS -->
</div>
```

And I want it to be this

```
<div>
    <!-- ME -->
</div>

<div>
    <!-- JANE -->
</div>

<div>
    <!-- JOHN -->
</div>

<div>
    <!-- MARK -->
</div>
```

Is it posible to do it using `orderBy` or do I have to reorganize my array of users ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom function to do the sorting, see this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/keagd91p/4/)**

```
$scope.sortUsers = function (user) {
    if (user.name === 'Me') {
        // return blank so it's always first in the order
        // you can also do 'return 0'; if the sorting is by ID.
        return ''; 
    }

    // return user.id; if by sorting is by ID
    return user.name;
};
```

Use this in the view

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: sortUsers">
    {{user.name}}<br/>
</div>
```

For more information, you can also look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat) and the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).