# Angular.js: How to order objects with orderby

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

Here is my angular code:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in list | orderBy:customOrderFn">
        <span>{{key}}: {{value.age}}</span>
    </li>

        app.controller('ListController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.list = {
                'name1': {
                    age: 22
                },
                'name2': {
                    age: 21
                },
                'name3': {
                    age: 23
                }
            }

            $scope.customOrderFn = function (person) {
                console.log(person);
                return person.age;
            }
```

I want to order by each person's age, so I using a custom order function. But this seems doesn't work.

So what's is wrong with my code? How can I fix it?

Comment: javascript objects don't have order ... use arrays. Using unique property names is more trouble than it's worth anyway for most of what you will be doing with this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

> Orders a specified array by the expression predicate. It is ordered
>   alphabetically for strings and numerically for numbers. Note: if you
>   notice numbers are not being sorted as expected, make sure they are
>   actually being saved as numbers and not strings.

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041694/2803660

It might help.