# Use method with orderBy in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

How can I use a method with orderBy ?

I would like to sort my array from ng-repeat with a method and not a property :

**index.html**

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in results.data | orderBy: product.getAllCounter()">
        <!-- Product name -->
        <td ng-bind="(product.product_offer[0].app_name === null) ? product.app.store_id : product.product_offer[0].app_name"></td>

        <!-- Counter -->
        <td class="text-right" ng-bind="product.getAllCounter()"></td>

        <!-- Action -->
        <td class="text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a ng-href="/#/product/{{ product.id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    See
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Product.prototype.getAllCounter**

```
// Return result all counter in promo
Product.prototype.getAllCounter = function () {
    var sum = 0;

    angular.forEach(this.product_promo_linker, function (product_promo_linker) {
        sum += product_promo_linker.promo.count;
    });

    return sum;
};
```

I tried with

> orderBy: product.getAllCounter()

and

> orderBy: product.getAllCounter

The method product.getAllCounter return integer

> SOLVED

I used :

```
<tr ng-repeat="campaign in results.data | orderBy: getAllCounter:true">
```

in my controller.js :

```
$scope.getCounter = function(product) {
    return campaign.getAllCounter();
};
```

Comment: Already there is a question similar to your problem. [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use custom ordering function then you need to provide one:

```
ng-repeat="product in results.data | orderBy: product.getAllCounter"
```

Note: no `()` after function name: you want to use function reference, not result of function invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass reference

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{
      name: 'foo',
      age: 2
    }, {
      name: 'bar',
      age: 1
    }, {
      name: 'baz',
      age: 3
    }]
    
    $scope.orderByAge = function(element) {
      return element.age
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<ul ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: orderByAge">
    {{ product.name }} - {{ product.age }}
  </li>
</ul>
```