# How to order strings by length with orderBy filter?

Tags: angularjs, string, typeahead

I have this code which work as expected providing me all the items starting with the letters I type in :

```
<input name="search-bar" id="search-bar" type="text"  ng-model="search" 
typeahead="res.label for res in result | filter:$viewValue:startsWith | 
limitTo:20">
```

But I want the suggestions to be ordered by the length of the `label`, so I tried two things without any luck :

1st try

```
<input name="search-bar" id="search-bar" type="text" ng-model="search" 
typeahead="res.label for res in result | filter:$viewValue:startsWith | 
limitTo:20 | orderBy:'res.label'">
```

2nd try

```
<input name="search-bar" id="search-bar" type="text" ng-model="search"
typeahead="res.label for res in result | filter:$viewValue:startsWith | 
limitTo:20 | orderBy:'res.label.length'">
```

EDIT (controller code) :

```
var url = "/data/list.json";
var items = $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        $scope.result = response.data; //result is filled with a static json containing all the data
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
```

JSON sample (from `/data/list.json`) :

```
[{"code":64,"label":"ALPAGA (64)"},{"code":44,"label":"ALPA (44)"}]
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: show controller code

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham Edited!

Comment: I think you don't need to use 'res', try this: orderBy:'label.length'"

Comment: yes you can use like this orderBy:'-label.length' or orderBy:'label.length'

Comment: And if is still doesn't work, you can try with a function comparing the length http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040395/custom-sort-function-in-ng-repeat

Comment: Did the trick, thank you guys !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `orderBy` routine like in this [runnable fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vv8k0c52/) or just try `orderBy:'label.length'` which directly interacts with the iterated object attribute. Both approaches should work for you in a fine way.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:orderByLength">
      {{ item.label }}
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "code": 64,
    "label": "ALPAGA (64)"
  }, {
    "code": 44,
    "label": "ALPA (44)"
  }, {
    "code": 24,
    "label": "ALPA (12344)"
  }, {
    "code": 48,
    "label": "ALPA (42324df)"
  }];

  $scope.orderByLength = function (item) {
      return item.label.length
  }
});
```